# Installing cassandra spark connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

As per

```
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
http://spark-packages.org/package/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector
```

I did the command but at the end it looks like there are errors. Are these fatal or do I need to resolve them?

```
[idf@node1 bin]$ spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.11
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/idf/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/idf/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.11 in spark-packages
        found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 in central
        found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 in central
        found io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 in list
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 in central
        found org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 in list
        found com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 in central
        found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in central
        found joda-time#joda-time;2.3 in central
        found com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 in central
        found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7 in list
        [2.11.7] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7
downloading http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/1.6.0-M1-s_2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-1.6.0-M1-s_2.11.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.11!spark-cassandra-connector.jar (2430ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/cassandra/cassandra-clientutil/3.0.2/cassandra-clientutil-3.0.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2!cassandra-clientutil.jar (195ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.0.0/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0!cassandra-driver-core.jar(bundle) (874ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1!guava.jar(bundle) (1930ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.joda#joda-convert;1.2!joda-convert.jar (68ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/joda-time-2.3.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] joda-time#joda-time;2.3!joda-time.jar (524ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0!jsr166e.jar (138ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.33.Final/netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final!netty-handler.jar (266ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.33.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final!netty-buffer.jar (202ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.33.Final/netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final!netty-transport.jar (330ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.33.Final/netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final!netty-codec.jar (157ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.33.Final/netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final!netty-common.jar (409ms)
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7!slf4j-api.jar (57ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 5827ms :: artifacts dl 7749ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 from central in [default]
        com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 from central in [default]
        com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from central in [default]
        datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.11 from spark-packages in [default]
        io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 from list in [default]
        io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        joda-time#joda-time;2.3 from central in [default]
        org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 from list in [default]
        org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 from central in [default]
        org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.7 from list in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   16  |   13  |   13  |   0   ||   16  |   13  |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
        confs: [default]
        16 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12730kB/549ms)
16/04/08 14:48:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in package.class refers to type compileTimeOnly
in package scala.annotation which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling package.class.
<console>:14: error: Reference to value sc should not have survived past type checking,
it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
                @transient val sc = {
                               ^
<console>:15: error: Reference to method createSQLContext in class SparkILoop should not have survived past type checking,
it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
                  val _sqlContext = org.apache.spark.repl.Main.interp.createSQLContext()
                                                                      ^
<console>:14: error: Reference to value sqlContext should not have survived past type checking,
it should have been processed and eliminated during expansion of an enclosing macro.
                @transient val sqlContext = {
                               ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
                ^

scala>
```

**EDIT 1**

When choosing the correct scala version, it seems to get much further, but I am uncertain if the output below still has what appears to be errors that need resolving:

```
[idf@node1 bin]$ spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/idf/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/idf/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/apach                                                                  e/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
datastax#spark-cassandra-connector added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.10 in spark-packages
        found org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 in central
        found com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 in central
        found io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final in central
        found io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 in list
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 in central
        found org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 in list
        found com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 in central
        found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in central
        found joda-time#joda-time;2.3 in central
        found com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 in central
        found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5 in list
downloading http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/1.6.0-M1-s_2.10/spark-cassandr                                                                  a-connector-1.6.0-M1-s_2.10.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.10!spark-cassandra-connector.jar (2414ms)
:: resolution report :: resolve 3281ms :: artifacts dl 2430ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.datastax.cassandra#cassandra-driver-core;3.0.0 from central in [default]
        com.google.guava#guava;16.0.1 from central in [default]
        com.twitter#jsr166e;1.1.0 from central in [default]
        datastax#spark-cassandra-connector;1.6.0-M1-s_2.10 from spark-packages in [default]
        io.dropwizard.metrics#metrics-core;3.1.2 from list in [default]
        io.netty#netty-buffer;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-codec;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-common;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-handler;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        io.netty#netty-transport;4.0.33.Final from central in [default]
        joda-time#joda-time;2.3 from central in [default]
        org.apache.cassandra#cassandra-clientutil;3.0.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.3.2 from list in [default]
        org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 from central in [default]
        org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.5 from list in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   16  |   6   |   6   |   0   ||   16  |   1   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
        unknown resolver null

        unknown resolver sbt-chain

        unknown resolver null


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
        confs: [default]
        2 artifacts copied, 14 already retrieved (5453kB/69ms)
16/04/08 15:50:20 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java cl                                                                  asses where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
16/04/08 15:50:28 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple J                                                                  AR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is alr                                                                  eady registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/                                                                  lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/04/08 15:50:28 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont hav                                                                  e multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9                                                                  .jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bi                                                                  n-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/04/08 15:50:28 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have mu                                                                  ltiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.j                                                                  ar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-                                                                  hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/04/08 15:50:45 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/04/08 15:50:45 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/04/08 15:50:49 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/04/08 15:50:49 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/04/08 15:50:49 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/opt/spark-latest/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/04/08 15:51:09 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/04/08 15:51:09 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose the Scala 2.11 version of the artifact `s_2.11`. You are most likely using Spark built with Scala 2.10 so use the `s_2.10` artifact

```
spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10
```

Comment: Thanks that appears to get me much farther. See EDIT 1: It looks like I still have errors though?

Comment: Ok was worried about "unknown resolver null unknown resolver sbt-chain" Don't know what those are and how it could hurt me.

Comment: Yeah don't worry about those :) Just means the dependency pull didn't go quite as planned but it still got all the artifacts it needed.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue when using package *com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1*. My command is

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1
```

I found the most reason why **unknown resolver null unknown resolver sbt-chain** issue happened is your spark version, your scala version and your package version is not consistent. So all thing you need to do is to find a proper package version.

For my package ***spark-redshift***

Scala 2.10

```
groupId: com.databricks
artifactId: spark-redshift_2.10
version: 2.0.1
```

Scala 2.11

```
groupId: com.databricks
artifactId: spark-redshift_2.11
version: 2.0.1
```